# How can I on-the-fly spellcheck XML in vim with XML tags excluded from being spellchecked?

Tags: xml, vim, spell-checking, docbook

My vim spellchecks docbook xml files very well, but underlines even bad words inside <tags>, which is a wrong behaviour. Anyone knows how to make it skip the tags from spellchecking?

Answer (score 0):

Which parts are spell-checked depends on the `@Spell` cluster attribute that is assigned to some syntax elements in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/xml.vim`. For example, the one on `xmlRegion` turns on spell checking inside XML tags.

You could copy the syntax script to `~/.vim/syntax/docbookxml` and then use that `'filetype'` instead of `xml` (or just `:setlocal syntax=docbookxml`).